# SF short story - Jewel ovary

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

This came out in the past 10 years, collected in one of the years best anthology.

Man stole a jewel from his girlfriend (turned out to be her refrigerated ovary). She then set him up in a double-cross.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. This is very terse at the moment. Could you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: Found the answer, how do I delete my Qn? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189045/short-story-where-technology-exists-to-hide-organic-matter-inside-inanimate-obje

Comment: There's no need to delete your question, you can post the answer yourself! See [answer] for more info

Comment: @JasonBrent I've marked this as a duplicate of the answer you found.